# explicit constructor taking `std::string` gets `char*` and works fine

Tags: c++, c++11

Marking `StringBuilder` constructor as explicit I think I couldn't pass in `char*` but it seems I can as it compiles just fine.

```
class StringBuilder {
public:
//    StringBuilder(const char *);
    explicit StringBuilder(std::string s) {}
};

int main() {

    StringBuilder s1("hello");
    StringBuilder s2(std::string("hello"));

}
```

http://cpp.sh/6uomq

Comment: `explicit` only means you can't implicitly convert an `std::string` to a `StringBuilder`, but `const char*` → `std::string` is still implicit… right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`basic_string` constructor taking a character pointer is not `explicit`:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,  Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

This means that providing a char pointer to function which takes `string` will implicitly create a string and pass it to the function.

You are making `StringBuilder` explicit, which means that it is not possible to implicitly convert `string` to `StringBuilder`, i.e. if you pass a `string` to a function which takes `StringBuilder` as argument, it will fail to compile.

EDIT: as noted by @Revolver_Ocelot, you can declare the offending constructor (`StringBuilder(const char*)`) as deleted to prevent it from being used. If you can't use C++11, you can just declare the same constructor as private and omit the definition (implementation):

```
class StringBuilder 
{
  public:
    explicit StringBuilder(const std::string& s) {}    

  // for C++11 use this:
    StringBuilder(const char*) = delete;

  // otherwise use this:
  private:
    StringBuilder(const char*); // no implementation
};
```

Comment: And to disallow that you can declare deleted constructor taking `const char*`

Comment: Thanks, now its clear. I misunderstood `explicit` keyword a bit :)